# Is my loop done wrong - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

Last time I checked I knew how to write a loop to display all my posts.....How ever when I wrote this:

```
if (have_posts()){
    while (have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <div clas="span6">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
}
```

I ran into an issue:

If I have the following posts:

**Post1, Post2, Post3**

Posts 1 - 2 will show up in a list, its only until I write a new post (Post 4) and publish it that post 3 will show up in that list.

So whats wrong with my loop?

never had this issue before.

**Note:** WordPress 3.5 is being used.

I have checked [WordPress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) to make sure I am doing things right and as far as I know I am.

Comment: @hd1 the `have_posts()` method is a wordpress method. See his linked documentation.

Comment: Nope, I am using that properly. I was reading the loop documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple things that could be causing your problems.  First, you have a set of `{ }` that are not needed.  Your open to the loop should be:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php if (have_posts()){ while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
```

See the curly brackets in your loop?

Then as McNab said, just fix your div class by adding the "s" and remove the `echo` from content pullers.

You also need to to include an `endif;` after your `endwhile;`.

So your full loop should loop like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="span6">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I think this should correct your problem.

Comment: that did not solve my problem. I still get only 3 our of the four posts

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below. This is mainly used in wordpress.

```
if (have_posts()) :  // your code if (have_posts()){
   while (have_posts()): the_post();
   ?>
   <div clas="span6">
      <h3><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <p><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
   </div>
   <?php
   endwhile;
endif; //your code here }
```

Hope it may work.

Comment: are your all post published, means any one is in draft or private.